# jQuery method not finding selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a simple jQuery function to pick up a selector from the html page and on keypress(up or down) should add a CSS class to it.

Problem is that it is not detecting the selector to add the class.

The HTML selector is nested deep into the code.

```
html
    body
        div.fixed-header
            div#main-nav.primary-nav.navbar
                div.navbar-inner
                    div.primary-nav-right-content
                        ul.nav
                             li#global-search
                                 div.search-results
                                      ul.search-dropdown
                                          ul.search-entry
```

I am trying to detect the selector ul.search-entry in my jquery.

What I have right now in my javascript is this.

```
var selector = $('ul.search-entry');
var selected;
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 40){
      if(selected){
          selected.removeClass('selected');
          next = selected.next();
          if(next.length > 0){
              selected = next.addClass('selected');
          }else{
              selected = selector.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
      }else{
          selected = selector.eq(0).addClass('selected');
      }
  }else if(e.which === 38){
      if(selected){
          selected.removeClass('selected');
          next = selected.prev();
          if(next.length > 0){
              selected = next.addClass('selected');
          }else{
              selected = selector.last().addClass('selected');
          }
      }else{
          selected = selector.last().addClass('selected');
      }
  }
  else{
  }
});
```

I have been racking my head for too long and I know am missing something really small. Any thoughts?

Comment: make sure the code is in a dom ready handler

Comment: `if (selected)`, `selected` is never given a value. Do you want `selector`?

Comment: @tymeJV When `if (selected)` is true, `selected` already has a value, so it doesn't need to be given one again.

Comment: *"Problem is that it is not detecting the selector to add the class."* What did you do to find out that no element is selected? Did you read the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)? *"To run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated, jQuery has a statement known as the [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)"*

Comment: Are you adding `ul.searchentry` elements dynamically? Your selector is being applied when the page first loads, so it won't include any elements that are added later.

Comment: I have a CSS to change the background and also am watching for the class to be added in when I 'Inspect Element' in chrome

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, the ul.search-entry is added dynamically. Is there a way to include the later added elements?

Comment: Call jQuery at the time you want to search, rather than caching the results in a variable.

Comment: Your question may be exposing a misunderstanding. `ul.search-entry` is a selector, `$("ul.search-entry")` is a jQuery collection of the elements that match the selector.

Comment: If you want to check that `ul.search-entry` exists on the page you can do `selector.is('*')` this will return `true` if the element is on the page.

Comment: @Barmar: I tried calling jQuery at the time of search but that made the function being called every time the search-dropdown changes. I need a way for it to kill the previous call and "restart" the function again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `selector` to just the selector string, not the collection that results, and call `jQuery` to search for it when needed.

```
var selector = 'ul.search-entry';
var selected;
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 40){
      if(selected){
          selected.removeClass('selected');
          next = selected.next();
          if(next.length > 0){
              selected = next.addClass('selected');
          }else{
              selected = $(selector).eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
      }else{
          selected = $(selector).eq(0).addClass('selected');
      }
  }else if(e.which === 38){
      if(selected){
          selected.removeClass('selected');
          next = selected.prev();
          if(next.length > 0){
              selected = next.addClass('selected');
          }else{
              selected = $(selector).last().addClass('selected');
          }
      }else{
          selected = $(selector).last().addClass('selected');
      }
  }
  else{
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes! This did it. I cannot believe it was this simple

Comment: Just did that. Thanks Felix.